# How to test methods?

Tags: java, eclipse

Quick question: I know myself that the method should return 12. But what if it were a more complex algorithm? Is there a specific way to test methods that will show the return in the console? Should call it in the main method?

```
 public class Alpha{


            int k = 4;
            int method1(int k){

            return k*3;
         }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

         }
```

*No, suprisingly enough I could not find another question similar to what I want.*

Comment: Google for "Java unit testing".

Answer (score 0):

To test code in Java, junit tests are used.

[JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/)